# Reading csv file and compare objects to a list

Tags: python

I have a .txt file,primary list, with strings like this:

```
f
r
y
h
g
j
```

and I have a .csv file,recipes list, with rows like this:

```
d,g,r,e,w,s
j,f,o,b,x,q,h
y,n,b,w,q,j
```

My programe is going throw each row and counts number of objects which belongs to primary list, for example in this case outcome is:
2
3
2
I always get 0, the mistake must be silly, but I can't figure it out:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv

primary_data =  open('test_list.txt','r') 
primary_list = [] 
for line in primary_data.readlines():
    line.strip('\n')
    primary_list.append(line)

recipes_reader = csv.reader(open('test.csv','r'), delimiter =',')

for row in recipes_reader:
    primary_count = 0
    for i in row:
        if i in primary_list:
            primary_count += 1
    print (primary_count)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the bare-essentials pedal-to-the-metal version:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv

with open('test_list.txt', 'r') as f: # with statement ensures your file is closed
    primary_set = set(line.strip() for line in f)

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f: #### see note below ###
    for row in csv.reader(f): # delimiter=',' is the default
        print(sum(i in primary_set for i in row)) # i in primary_set has int value 0 or 1
```

Note: In Python 2.x, always open csv files in binary mode. In Python3.x, always open csv files with `newline=''`

Answer (score 0):

The reading into `primary_list` adds `\n` to each number - you should remove it:

When appending to `primary_list` do:

```
for line in primary_data:
    primary_list.append(line.strip())
```

Note the `strip` call. Also, as you can see, you don't really need `realines`, since `for line in primary_data` already does what you need when `primary_data` is a file object.

Now, as a general comment, since you're using the primary list for lookup, I suggest replacing the list by a set - this will make things much faster if the list is large. Python sets are very efficient for key-based lookup, lists are not designed for that purpose.

Comment: I edited my code, still I got 0. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @masti: I get "2 3 2" printed out (each on a line of its own)(

Comment: @masti: If you are interested in working out why you still got 0, insert `print(primary_list)` and check its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Following code would solve the problem.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv
primary_data =  open('test_list.txt','r')

primary_list = [line.rstrip() for line in primary_data]

recipies_reader = csv.reader(open('recipies.csv','r'), delimiter =',')
for row in recipies_reader:
    count = 0
    for i in row:
       if i in primary_list:
           count += 1

    print (count)
```

**Output**

```
2
3
2
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to remove '\n' from characters by my code but I couldn't. However your code works fine :)